# How can I make a div that is set in pixels resize according to the page?

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a progress bar that uses arrows but the only way I know how to make it is using pixels. So I am wondering if there is a way to create this progress bar using pixels, and then change its size according to the page. I have looked at similar questions, but none pertain to the type of element I am creating. Attached is what the bar currently looks like, and I want to be able to make it adaptable to the screen size.

```
.containerr {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapperr {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow:auto;*/
}

.pull-right {
}

a:hover {
  color: #999;
}

/* Breadcrups CSS */
.arrow-steps {
  zoom: 1.4;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.arrow-steps .step {
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0 3px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  min-width: 180px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d9e3f7;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}
.arrow-steps .step:after, .arrow-steps .step:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -17px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid #d9e3f7;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

.arrow-steps .step:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 17px solid #333;
  z-index: 0;
}

.arrow-steps .step:first-child:before {
  border: none;
}

.arrow-steps .step:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.arrow-steps .step span {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-steps .step span:before {
  opacity: 0;
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -20px;
}

.arrow-steps .step.done span:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
}

.arrow-steps .step.current {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #23468c;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
}
```

html

```
<div class="containerr">
  <div class="wrapperr">
    <div class="arrow-steps clearfix">
      <div runat="server" id="first" class="step">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="machineLink" CssClass="arrowTexts" runat="server" OnClick="machineLink_Click" OnClientClick="getCoordinates()">Safety</asp:LinkButton>
      </div>
      <div runat="server" id="second" class="step">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="estopLink" CssClass="arrowTexts" runat="server" OnClick="estop_Click" OnClientClick="getCoordinates()">Estop Reset
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </div>
      <div runat="server" id="third" class="step">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="startLink" CssClass="arrowTexts" runat="server" OnClick="start_Click" OnClientClick="getCoordinates()">Start</asp:LinkButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML code? Also - you can use `vw` and `vh` instead of `px` to make your progress-bar responsive

Comment: ..also ..`vertical-align:central;` is not a thing.

Comment: @fen1x I know I can use those but I don't know how to do that for my situation since borders cannot use % or vh or vw to change their sizes.

Comment: You don't use borders in anything except pseudo-elements, so it won't take up space. Why don't you apply something like `width:32%; margin:0 0.5%` to `.step`?

Comment: @fen1x that unfortunately did not work, and the borders are being used to create the arrow shape of the div.

Comment: @P.Griffin see [this pen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/RZNLbZ?editors=1100). Though, it still breaks on very small window width.

Comment: @fen1x thank you that really helped! How would I get it to also change according to the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `vh` `vw` `vmin` and `vmax` to make your progress-bar responsive.
See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/RZNLbZ?editors=1100)